# Unable to print Javax Object Contesnts

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to use [mkyong's JAXB Hello World example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) and am unable to print the contents of the entire class, although I am able to print specific elements.  The output should be:

```
    Customer [name=mkyong, age=29, id=100]
    100
    29
```

Here's my output:

```
    xml_test.Customer@eed1f14
    100
    29
```

I am currently running Java 1.8 via Netbeans 8.2 on a Windows 10 box.  Note that there are some other includes in here because my next step is to work with a list of the customer objects (that may be the subject of another question).

Here's my object (which I believe to be the same as his):

```
package xml_test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.List;


@XmlRootElement
class Customer {

String name;
int age;
int id;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@XmlElement
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

@XmlElement
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

@XmlAttribute
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

Here's my code:

```
    package xml_test;


    import java.io.File;
    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
    import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

    public class XML_Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

         try {

            File file = new File("S:\\file.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
                    System.out.println(customer);
                /* Added for testing  */   
                    System.out.println(customer.id);
                    System.out.println(customer.age);

          } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

        }
```

Here's my data file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <customer id="100">
        <age>29</age>
        <name>mkyong</name>
    </customer>
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
xml_test.Customer@eed1f14
```

this you are getting as you are printing `customer` object. 
Since you have not override Object class method `public String toString()` , so what are getting is expected.

So, to get this `Customer [name=mkyong, age=29, id=100]`
 you have to override something as this:
`@Override
public String toString() {
return “Customer [name=” + name + “, age=” + age + “, id=” + id + “]”;
}` 
in your Customer class

Comment: You are welcome. If it helps/solves your issue, you can accept this answer.